# Android get time format

Tags: android, datetime, format

Is there a nice way to retriev the time format e.g. 24h or 12h from within an android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context)